# Usergrid query on unknown sub properties

Tags: apache, wildcard, apigee, usergrid, apigee-baas

I'm trying to query a collection of data with entities that contain the "related" property:

```
...,{ related : 
       { global: [{name: "foo"}, {name: "bar"}] },
       { local: [{name: "bar"}] },
       { random: [{name: "foo"}] },
       { dingbat: [{name: "baz"}] },
    }
```

I want to write a query which selects all entities which have name="foo" anywhere within the related property.

I can do this just fine:

```
select * where related.global.name='foo'
```

However there could be any number of keys within the "related" property so I can't just AND them all into a single query.  Trying to do something like this (which doesn't work)

```
select * where related.*.name='foo'
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at this time.  However, it is something we could consider for the future.  We have ElasticSearch for indexing in our 2.1 platform and we can use the '_all' functionality from ES but we have not exposed that in Usergrid yet.

Comment: Could I write a query to get all the keys that exist in the related property?